# Can't upgrade Emacs from 24.3.1 to 24.5 in a CentOS 7 vm

Tags: emacs, centos, vagrant

I have a CentOS 7 Vagrant virtual machine that I'd like to do some development work from. Accordingly, I'd like the latest version of Emacs (24.5) so that I can install Spacemacs.

However, when I ssh into the box and run the command `sudo yum update emacs` and `sudo yum upgrade emacs`, I simply get back the message `No packages marked for update`. I've also run `yum update` and `yum upgrade` to no avail.

So how do I go about getting me some sweet sweet Emacs 24.5? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The latest RPM [I could find](http://rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=emacs&submit=Search+...&system=centos&arch=) for emacs on CentOS 7 (7.2) is 24.3.

You can install it via yum with the following code, after downloading the rpm:

```
yum localinstall emacs-24.3-18.el7.x86_64.rpm
```

If you want to compile it yourself, there is a [Github repo](https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs) with the source and instructions on how to do that.

They also have [tagged releases](https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/releases) if you prefer something a little more stable to choose from.

As of this post, the latest version they have available is emacs-25.0.92, with releases going back to the version you requested.

Answer (score 0):

Is compiling Emacs 24.5 an option for you? It shouldn't be a big deal.

My answer assumes that you performed a *reasonable* online search, without success, for a yum repository containing that particular version of Emacs.

Comment: I goog'd for upgrading emacs... however, I'm still learning how to use centos so it never occurred to me to look for an unofficial yum repo for emacs.